# What is the correct repo url to install com.amazonaws.eclipse.ec2 maven dependency?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am working with an eclipse build (Tycho) and I have to add the aws toolkit using the following repo configuration:

```
<repository>
    <id>aws</id>
    <url>https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/</url>
    <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

But when I run **mvn clean install**, I got the following issue:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'aws' from location https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/: The p2 repository at https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse contains partial IUs (see above) from an old style update site which cannot be used for dependency resolution -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'aws' from location https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/
```

If I use the same url (https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse) in Eclipse (Help > Install new software...) the repository works. My question here is what is the correct URL to use in maven repositories or how can install those plugins in my tycho build?
Regards.

Comment: It's an Eclipse plugin, not maven repository. Why do you think you need to add that as a maven repository? I don't think you should do that.

Comment: If you want to use AWS SDK in your project refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html but that has no relation to Eclipse plugin